# How to add useState array as a useState List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-state

I have an array coming from api which I am storing in a state, I want to store that array in another state as a List of objects where each array element would be a value with some Id
i-e
original array = `["value1","value2"....,"value(n)"]`
converted to List = `[{value: "value1", id: 1}, {value: "value2", id: 2}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in simple terms is using a `map()` function. Your code should be something like this:

```
(value, id) => ({ value, id: id + 1 })
```

And here's the working snippet:

```js
const arr = ["value1","value2","value(n)"];
const obj = arr.map((value, id) => ({value, id}));
console.log(obj);
```

If you want the values to be **one-indexed**, you can change it this way:

```js
const arr = ["value1", "value2", "value(n)"];
const obj = arr.map((value, id) => ({
  value,
  id: id + 1
}));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the work around for variables but for states it works differently I guess @Praveen

Comment: @user11832873 Please show the full code so that we can help.

Comment: You store variables in the state, from what I can see Praveen's answer is perfectly acceptable and correct

Comment: @user11832873 I'm assuming the part of the state you're looking to store this modified array inside is the list, so all you do is use the map function that Praveen has mentioned above and then you call setList(obj); (obj being the result of the map function)

Comment: Thanks @user11832873 You can use the `setValue` function to set it right way.

Comment: @user11832873 Ask another question with the React specific query, I'll be more than happy to answer it.